# Linear regression model is under-predicting

Tags: regression, residuals

Based on this y vs. residual plot, where `residual = y - prediction`, it appears that my linear regression model is systematically under-predicting on `y > 0.02`. Could it be due to heteroskedastic errors? I'm modeling time series data, and I've plotted the residuals time series plot underneath the y vs. residual plot. I'd specifically like to know why the residuals are strictly positive for large y.

[image: y_resid]
[image: resid]
[image: resid autocor]
[image: y autocor]
[image: y dist]
[image: resid dist]

Comment: You data has strong autocorrelation.

Comment: Both x and y are positively skewed which will give you positively skewed residuals.

Comment: How can we tell that the residuals are "strictly positive for large y"? None of your plots conveys that information and it's inadequately quantified: *how* large is "large" and *how many* such observations are involved?  BTW, there's little evidence of any autocorrelation, either, so that's unlikely to be a factor.

Comment: I disagree that the residuals are autocorrelated - I've added some new plots to demonstrate. However, I agree that the dependent variable is positively skewed - is this ok if my only goal is prediction?

Comment: Your dependent variable is *negatively* skewed.  The skewness appears reversed in some of the plots because you (or your software) has computed the negatives of the residuals.

Comment: @whuber I mentioned `y > 0.02` as a rough cutoff, and drawing a vertical line in the top y vs. residual plot shows that the residuals are for the vast majority positive for `y > 0.02`.

Comment: I have defined `residual = y - prediction`, but if I were to define it instead as `residual = prediction - y`, my plots would be negatively skewed. Is this preferred?

Comment: (1) You plots *still* do not provide any evidence related to your claim of positive residuals for large $y$ values!  (2) The way to compute residuals is currently being hashed out at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342466.  Your plots suggested a good way to resolve the question, and so I posted an answer that refers to your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76509/discussion-between-tmakino-and-whuber).

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be one of two things (I would have to take a look at your data to say for sure):

- either your data has high homoskedasticity
- or your data is strongly auto-correlated (a typical characteristic of time series)

Comment: You cannot have high homoskedasticity.  You are either homoskedastic or you are not homoskedastic.  It is a binary choice.

Comment: @DaveHarris If you only consider p-value cutoffs (e.g. p < 0.05) as the magic number, then it is binary. But if you look at the correct measure (the effect size, e.g. the actual value of W or F for the Levene's test), then a distribution can most certainly be highly homoskedastic versus not much. Even though it is traditional to only consider p < 0.05, it is always more meaningful to actually consider the value of the effect size.